# AES not work properly in StringSource and StringSink functions in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, aes, crypto++, cbc-mode

I have using of **Crypto++** library in **Qt** due to encrypt a string with `AES` method in `CBC` mode and using of `StringSource` and `StringSink` to  define `input` and `output` string parameters.

First, i read all bytes from a file ("unicode" or "ASCII" encoding), then set it as the `input` parameter in `StringSource` function, then set a parameter as `string`(data-type) for output (cipher-text). just i want to get a string and encrypt it with "aes-cbc" and showing output.

Also, i know `FileSource` and `FileSink` are two functions(consist `input` and `output` stream parameters) for writing data to files! but i want to read file content as input-string.

**My Code :**

```
void Widget::onEncryptButton()
{
    QByteArray key = "qwertyuiopasdfgh";
    QByteArray iv = "wertyuiopasdfghj"
    QByteArray plain;
    string cipher;

    QFile fi("/home/msi/Desktop/input.txt");
    QFile fo("/home/msi/Desktop/output.enc");

    fi.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    fo.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
    plain = fi.readAll();

    AESEncryption aese((byte*)key.constData(), AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);    // default is 16
    CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption encryptor(aese, (byte*)iv.constData());
    StringSource(plain, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encryptor, new StringSink(cipher)));

    QMessageBox::information(this, "", QString("%1, %2").arg(strlen(cipher.c_str())).arg(cipher.size()));    // just for viewing cipher length

    fo.write(cipher.c_str());
    fi.close();
    fo.close();
}
```

Now i have bellow problems :

- When i read a compact file content(e.g. 900 byte) and set it as input in `StringSource`, generated cipher will be incomplete (e.g. 320 byte)
- Output of `strlen(cipher.c_str())` is different by `cipher.size()` in "QMessageBox"
- My code working truly When i read some files("unicode" or "ASCII", "larg" or "little" size) and sometimes working incorrectly. i dont understand which of the reason caused this problem?
- Even, i set some input-string directly (not reading from file) and fails again!

Regards!

Comment: `QByteArray plain;` and `StringSource(plain, true, ...);` should cause a compile failure. `StringSource` does *not* have a ctor that takes a `QByteArray`. You should probably add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compile flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be your `plain`, if it contains '\0'. Try to pass both, the data and the length:

```
StringSource((byte*)plain.constData(), plain.size(), true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encryptor, new StringSink(cipher)));
```

Comment: i test with a file without '\0' and pass `data` and `length` but not work truly!

Comment: but still there is this problem ---> Output of `strlen(cipher.c_str())` is different by `cipher.size()` in "QMessageBox"

Answer (score 1):

I would consider reworking the function:

```
// Improve this in real life
QByteArray key = "qwertyuiopasdfgh";
QByteArray iv = "wertyuiopasdfghj"

std::string infile("/home/msi/Desktop/input.txt");
std::string outfile("/home/msi/Desktop/output.enc");

CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryptor(key.constData(), key.size(), iv.constData());
FileSource fs(infile.c_str(), true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encryptor, new FileSink(outfile.c_str())));
```

Using the [`FileSource`](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/FileSource) and [`FileSink`](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/FileSink) avoids the problems with trying to interpret the data under a character set. It also saves on the extra copies, and its friendlier with Mobile devices and IoT gadgets which don't have a lot of RAM.

You might also consider using an [Authenticated Encryption mode](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) to ensure both confidentiality and authenticity.

Answer (score 0):

I replace bellow statement:

```
StringSource((byte*)plain.constData(), plain.size(), true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encryptor, new StringSink(cipher)));
```

With the bellow :

```
StringSource(plain, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encryptor, new StringSink(cipher)));
```

Then, i rebuild program again, but problem was still!

I <strike>temporarily</strike> remove all '\' characters from the plaintext and compile again, after that, the output cipher showed truly in "QMessageBox" with `cipher.size()` statement.

then replace

```
fo.write(cipher.c_str(), cipher.size());
```

with :

```
fo.write(cipher.c_str());
```

I do These instructions for encryption and decryption sections.

Comment: *"... replace `fo.write(cipher.c_str(), cipher.size());` with `fo.write(cipher.c_str());`..."* - you are probably truncating your cipher text on the first embedded NULL character. It means you will recover part of your plain text.